# AttributeError when trying to get from the shutil module .make_archive

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am trying to use the shutil module to zip some files using the code below:

```
import shutil
shutil.name_archive("output", "zip", "files")
print(dir(shutil))
```

That code produced the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\franko\shutil.py", line 1, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\franko\shutil.py", line 3, in <module>
    new = shutil.name_archive("output", "zip", "files")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'shutil' has no attribute 'name_archive' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I expect the documents in the files directory I created to be in zip mode. How can I zip these files?

Answer (score 0):

Your python file name is `shutil.py`.

This is causing circular import.

Please change this name to something else because module name is `shutil` as well.

Moreover, `shutil` does not have `name_archive` it should be :

`shutil.make_archive("output", "zip", "files")`